# convert RESPONSE BODY image to base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

### How to convert an image into a `base64` string?

```js
var request = require('request');

let options = {
  url: imgUrl,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": imgauth
  },
  contentType: "base64"
};

//request response Content-type : 'image/png'
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
  var base64data = new Buffer(body, 'binary').toString('base64');
  console.log(base64data);
});
```

I have used the code above to do so, but it does not work.

Comment: What debugging have you done with the browser's built in tools?

Comment: No am not debugging from browser ...am doing from NodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set request `encoding` to null and get the file content and then try to convert it to `base64` using node's core `buffer()` functionality.

See request [documentation here](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) and [here](https://github.com/request/request#requestdefaultsoptions)

```
const Request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });

let options = {
    url: imgUrl,
    headers: { "Authorization": imgauth }
};

Request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let imagedata = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
        console.log(imagedata);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is dataURI ? it's like png or string

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you requesting an image file? where are you using it?

Comment: ya am requesting a image file only,that response body ll be a image,i need to convert that image to base64

Comment: what is the use case on gettting image file on node server? Are you trying to cache the image? You better user `fs` library for that purpose.

Comment: let us know your actual requirment that we can help you better

Comment: Actually am trying to send a mail with contain images in respective mail.

Comment: why can you put the imgUrl as it is in the `<img src />` instead of getting the file from file URL, converting it into base64 encoded value and setting it as image src again? isn't it an overkill for the purpose?

Comment: ya we tired that too,but that image url based on authentication so we can't simply put the URL in image src